# How to use dask jupyterlab extensions behind nginx proxy

Tags: nginx, dask, jupyterhub

Im running a small scientific cluster in our lab. Jupyterhub is installed to run jupyter notebooks with python/julia/r for multiple users. we are new to dask

Dask and the jupyterlab extensions work fine if I run them locally on a node and acces through 127.0.0.1
However I can’t get dask to play nice with the nginx proxy we normally use to connect to jupyterhub. The status pages still point to 127.0.0.1 instead of the access node IP.
Any hints are appreciated.

Our setup

Nginx<——->jupyterhub on access node
Slurm scheduler
8 compute nodes
All on same subnet

Answer (score 0):

somehow, I'm not the only one. see this thread:
https://github.com/dask/dask-labextension/issues/41
however, it is totally unclear for me howto tackle this since..
If someone could outline the steps it would be really helpful.

Comment: This seems to be a general issue with Jupyter notebooks behind a proxy. The exact same thing is also true for inline dash (not dask) applications. basically we need something that takes the running server on localhost at <port> and proxies it to the inline results in the jupyter notebook